# Gamma won't restore to original settings after exiting 3d application

Tags: windows-7, brightness

I have adjusted my gamma, brightness and contrast using the calibration tool provided by Windows 7. Games typically require slightly different settings in my experience, and so I tend to adjust the gamma / brightness on an ad hoc basis depending on the game. The problem is that once I exit, the Windows 7 settings do not restore themselves, but instead I'm stuck with gamma settings that I configured in-game.  Is there a way to have Windows restore settings after the game/program shuts down?

GPU: Nvidia GTX 580
Driver: 275.33

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a permanent solution, the quickest way to restore your original gamma settings is by resetting the display driver using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Your screens should go black for a second and you should hear a beep after which your screens should be restored.